# Data is truncating when sent in Gzipped format

Tags: apache-2.4, gzip

I am sending gzipped data from the client to the Apache server and getting it inflated at the Apache layer (Using https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html#input).
The data is then sent from Apache to Tomcat, however, at Tomcat I am getting truncated data.

Looked for this and found below bug raised against Apache server.
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34526

As per the solution mentioned in the above link, I am required to add an Apache environment variable "JK_IGNORE_CL".
I tried to set this variable, however, I am not able to get it to work.
Below is the Directive I used to set this property (Inside .htaccess file). I am trying to set this variable only if, the request has Content-Encoding as gzip.

> SetEnvIf Content-Encoding gzip JK_IGNORE_CL

I also tried to provide some value like, JK_IGNORE_CL=true or JK_IGNORE_CL=1 to it as well,
however, it did not work. I am not sure, what is the expected way to enable this.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So it turns out that the above setting was indeed working, however, in absence of Content-Length, mod_jk can only send a maximum of 8kb of **un-compressed** data to Tomcat (It can be increased to a maximum of 64kb, 'max_packet_size') and the data I was sending was more than that, in some cases.

So that is the limit we need to live with, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to set the environmental variable for apache. IIRC these days that is done in `/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/override.conf` and you're after content like

```
[Service]
Environment=JK_IGNORE_CL=true
```

You didn't specify what `JK_IGNORE_CL` should be set to so I've assumed `true`

Comment: Thanks Timothy, I'll look into it. Regarding the value of JK_IGNORE_CL, it is not mentioned in the Apache documentation, that what should be its value. Its just mentioned that this variable shall be set. So I tried with true, yes etc, with no success. Also I need to specify this for only those request having Content Encoding as gzip.